# cumulative sum and adding rows where instance does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am creating an unpivoted table with that has cumulative sum.

The data is as follows:

```
Year     Period     Amount    
2011        1         10    
2011        2         15    
2011        3         8   
2012        1         20    
2012        3         10    
2012        4         5
```

I want to add a cumulative sum:

```
Year     Period     Cumulative Amount   
2011        1         10    
2011        2         25  
2011        3         33   
2012        1         20   
2012        3         30   
2012        4         35
```

I wrote the code for this cumulative sum but my problem is that in the instance for Year 2012 Period 2 these is no record so it wouldn't appear.

What is the easiest way to add rows where there are no records and have the amount = 0?

for year 2011 there needs to be 2019 - 2011 + 1 = 9 periods
for year 2012 there needs to be 2019 - 2012 + 1 = 8 periods
… and so on.

To get the cumulative sum I did the following:

```
py_data = df['Amount'].groupby([df['Year'], df['Period']).sum().reset_index()

py_data['cumsum'] = py_data["'Amount'"].groupby([py_data['Period']]).cumsum()
```

Comment: Do you need add missing rows? But in output is not `2012        2         0`. Or only cumsum ?

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
df['Cumulative_Amount'] = df.groupby('Year')['Amount'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   Year  Amount  Period  Cumulative_Amount
0  2011      10       1                 10
1  2011      15       2                 25
2  2011       8       3                 33
3  2012      20       1                 20
4  2012      10       3                 30
5  2012       5       4                 35
```

Comment: You still have Period 2 for Year 2012 missing. I want a new row with Year 2012 and Period 2 amount to appear.